# Compare financial data from this week to the same week last year

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to compare financial data from this week to the same week last year.. my table is

```
        amount  storecode   date
        0.00    0000000001  2010-12-21 14:01:00
        0.00    0000000001  2010-12-21 14:01:00
        0.00    0000000001  2010-12-21 14:57:50
        10.00   0000000001  2010-12-21 14:57:50
        2.35    0000000001  2010-12-21 14:57:50
        45.00   0000000001  2010-12-21 14:57:50
        0.00    0000000001  2010-12-21 14:57:50
        -10.00  0000000001  2010-12-21 14:57:50
        -2.35   0000000001  2010-12-21 14:57:50
        -45.00  0000000001  2010-12-21 14:57:50
        ...................etc...etc to 2014
```

I have tried numerous different intervals but i cannot find something which is accurate for my boss to see a comparison between this week and the same week last year..

i even tried joining it with another table so as to give the storecode aphabetic visual representation rather than the numeric form

```
        SELECT distinct(`stores`.`StoreLocation`) as branch, SUM(`TRANSACTIONS`.`Amount`) as AmountTendered , DATE(`TRANSACTIONS`.`Date`) as Dates FROM transactions LEFT JOIN stores ON stores.StoreCode = transactions.Storecode WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 year) <= DATE(Date) group by YEAR(Date)
```

Comment: Probably the first thing to clarify is how do you define the same week of a previous year? From the same date? The same ISO week number? From Mon through Sun? From the nth Monday of the month?

Comment: it just has to go by month mainly, as our business is seasonal so its good to see the figures on average and it can be out by a week or 2

Comment: Are you allowed to create a temporary table along the way?  What I'd do, roughly speaking, is create another table in which the original data is grouped and summed by WeekOfYear(date) and Year(date); then do a self-join on the new table for the comparison.

Comment: that sounds good to me, for the moment... i am building a dashboard for my boss and basically it has to create itself everyday and display it to him via google spreadsheet so obviously a temporary table wouldnt cut the mustard there but i would be very interested to see how you would implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't sound confident you understand how you want (or more specifically how your boss wants to correlate the weeks' value from one year to another (*go by month mainly* and *and it can be out by a week or 2*).

Here is a starting point based on the data you shared

Example of last year's report

```
SELECT YEAR(`date`) AS `year`
    , WEEKOFYEAR(`date`) AS weekno
    ,Storecode AS storecode
    , SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM transactions
WHERE YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
GROUP BY YEAR(`date`), WEEKOFYEAR(`date`), Storecode
```

Here is an example of that query with comparisons

```
SELECT this.storecode 
   , this.weekno
   , this.amount AS current_amount
   , history.amount AS past_amount
FROM (SELECT YEAR(`date`) AS `year`
        , WEEKOFYEAR(`date`) AS weekno
        ,Storecode AS storecode
        , SUM(amount) AS amount
      FROM transactions
      WHERE YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(NOW())
      GROUP BY YEAR(`date`), WEEKOFYEAR(`date`), Storecode) AS this
JOIN (SELECT YEAR(`date`) AS `year`
        , WEEKOFYEAR(`date`) AS weekno
        ,Storecode AS storecode
        , SUM(amount) AS amount
      FROM transactions
      WHERE YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
      GROUP BY YEAR(`date`), WEEKOFYEAR(`date`), Storecode) AS history
  ON this.weekno = history.weekno
    AND this.storecode = history.storecode;
```

Comment: VERY NICE, BUT WHEN I TRY TO ADD IN THE StoreCode which is essentially an id, it doesnt give me the correct results, but very nice indeed. there are 5 different store codes, how can i get the comparisons and also further segment them by store

Comment: You have to add the store code in all of these places.  (1) the main `SELECT`; (2) each of the two `SELECT` clauses in the parentheses; (3) each of the two `GROUP BY` clauses in parentheses; (4) the `ON` clause at the end (use an `AND` for this).